# Select * gives an amount but using column names gives 0

Tags: mysql, sql

In the following query:

```
SELECT order_id,
       payment_index,
       payment_status,
       payment_type,
       orig_payment_type,
       subpayment_type,
       transaction_id,
       payment_amount,
       SUM(total_pending_refund_amount)    as total_pending_refund_amount,
       SUM(total_processing_refund_amount) as total_processing_refund_amount,
       SUM(total_completed_refund_amount)  as total_completed_refund_amount
FROM (
         SELECT rop.order_id,
                NULL                                    as payment_index,
                NULL                                    as payment_status,
                NULL                                    as subpayment_type,
                NULL                                    as payment_type,
                NULL                                    as orig_payment_type,
                NULL                                    as transaction_id,
                (o.bill_amount + o.tax + o.tip + o.fee) as payment_amount,
                SUM(rop.amount)                         as total_pending_refund_amount,
                0                                       as total_processing_refund_amount,
                0                                       as total_completed_refund_amount
         FROM refund_order_payments rop
                  JOIN orders o ON rop.order_id = o.id AND rop.order_id = '32799'
         WHERE rop.refund_status = 'PENDING'
           AND rop.payment_index IS NULL

         UNION

         SELECT rop.order_id,
                NULL                                    as payment_index,
                NULL                                    as payment_status,
                NULL                                    as payment_type,
                NULL                                    as subpayment_type,
                NULL                                    as orig_payment_type,
                NULL                                    as transaction_id,
                (o.bill_amount + o.tax + o.tip + o.fee) as payment_amount,
                0                                       as total_pending_refund_amount,
                SUM(rop.amount)                         as total_processing_refund_amount,
                0                                       as total_completed_refund_amount
         FROM refund_order_payments rop
                  JOIN orders o ON rop.order_id = o.id AND rop.order_id = '32799'
         WHERE rop.refund_status = 'IN_PROCESS'
           AND rop.payment_index IS NULL

         UNION

         SELECT rop.order_id,
                NULL                                    as payment_index,
                NULL                                    as payment_status,
                NULL                                    as payment_type,
                NULL                                    as subpayment_type,
                NULL                                    as orig_payment_type,
                NULL                                    as transaction_id,
                (o.bill_amount + o.tax + o.tip + o.fee) as payment_amount,
                0                                       as total_pending_refund_amount,
                0                                       as total_processing_refund_amount,
                SUM(rop.amount)                         as total_completed_refund_amount
         FROM refund_order_payments rop
                  JOIN orders o ON rop.order_id = o.id AND rop.order_id = '32799'
         WHERE rop.refund_status = 'COMPLETED'
           AND rop.payment_index IS NULL
     ) t
GROUP BY t.payment_index;
```

`payment_amount` is 0.

However, when I do `select *`, I get the result (4.00).

Why is this? The name seems the same

[image]

[image]

**EDIT** It seems that the problem are the SUM clauses, because commenting them makes the correct result show.

**EDIT 2** In the 3 results of the subquery, the payment_amount is 4.00

**EDIT 3** The SUM clauses has 0 in one of the 3 subqueries
[image]

Comment: COUNT only counts rows with non-null values in the specified fields; using COUNT(1) (a non-null value eg.) or COUNT(star) will count all rows.

Comment: @DressyFiddle that's a table alias which is required.

Comment: @Nick I found the problem, the SUM clauses. Why is this?

Comment: Does your query with `SELECT *` not have a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Nick it has, I only change the SELECT xxx to SELECT *. That is the only change. Removing the SUM also works to get the 4.00 value

Comment: Your issue is that you're only grouping by `payment_index` so the values of `payment_status,
       payment_type,
       orig_payment_type,
       subpayment_type,
       transaction_id,
       payment_amount` will be selected from a random row in the `t` table. You need some form of aggregation formula around those columns too (e.g. MIN/MAX/SUM)

Comment: @Nick in all 3 rows of the subquery, payment amount is 4.00

Comment: You've got grouping issues in the subquery too - you have an aggregation function with no `group by`. So the results of the subquery will also be indeterminate for the non-aggregated columns, and may change dependent on the behaviour of the query optimiser

Answer (score 2):

I think you can resolve your issues by rewriting your query using conditional aggregation in a subquery:

```
SELECT rop.order_id,
       NULL                                    as payment_index,
       NULL                                    as payment_status,
       NULL                                    as subpayment_type,
       NULL                                    as payment_type,
       NULL                                    as orig_payment_type,
       NULL                                    as transaction_id,
       (o.bill_amount + o.tax + o.tip + o.fee) as payment_amount,
       total_pending_refund_amount,
       total_processing_refund_amount,
       total_completed_refund_amount
FROM (
  SELECT order_id,
         SUM(CASE WHEN refund_status = 'PENDING' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)    as total_pending_refund_amount,
         SUM(CASE WHEN refund_status = 'IN_PROCESS' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as total_processing_refund_amount,
         SUM(CASE WHEN refund_status = 'COMPLETED' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)  as total_completed_refund_amount
  FROM refund_order_payments
  WHERE order_id = '32799' AND payment_index IS NULL
  GROUP BY order_id) rop
JOIN orders o ON rop.order_id = o.id
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you basically want conditional aggregation.

I recommend starting with this version of the query:

```
select sum(o.bill_amount + o.tax + o.tip + o.fee) as payment,
       sum(case when refund_status = 'PENDING' then rop.amount end) as completed_amount
       sum(case when refund_status = 'IN_PROCESS' then rop.amount end) as inprocess_amount
       sum(case when refund_status = 'COMPLETED' then rop.amount end) as completed_amount
from refund_order_payments rop join
     orders o on
     on rop.order_id = o.id and rop.order_id = '32799'
where rop.payment_index is null;
```

Most of the rest of the columns do not add anything meaningful the result set.  But if there is more information that you want, you should add it to a working query.